# Why doesn't htop show LED mode meters with box-drawing characters?

Tags: debian, unicode, htop

I just set up htop on a server running Debian and noticed that meters in LED more are rendered with letters and symbols instead of the box-drawing chars it uses on my Mac.

For comparison, htop on Debian:

[image: Screenshot of htop running on a Debian server]

htop on macOS:

[image: Screenshot of htop displaying the uptime meter on macOS]

While googling for solutions, I found [this Unix SE question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97688/terminal-displaying-special-characters) whose solution was basically "you're running with a non-Unicode locale", but that's not the case here, as my server's configured to use the `en_US.UTF-8` locale.

Is there a way to change the LED render method to box-drawing characters?

Comment: Do you run it through ssh or locally?

Comment: The first screenshot was taken while I was connected to my server over ssh. The second one is from a local terminal on macOS.